# Pass image in a new window in WPF/C#

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I've got some images in a ListBox. When the user clicks one image, I'd like to open a new window (ImageWindow) and show the clicked image in the new window. I've added already a new XAML-file and a eventhandler. This is what I got:

MainWindow:

```
<ListBox Name="MainListBox">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Image Source="{Binding}" MouseDown="Image_MouseDown"></Image>
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

/*========================================================================*/

private void Image_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ImageWindow imageWindow = new ImageWindow();
    //Pass image
    imageWindow.Show();
}
```

ImageWindow:

```
<ListBox Name="ImageListBox">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Image Source="{Binding}"></Image>
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

How do I pass the clicked image?

See [example](https://www.digitec.ch/de/s1/product/hp-officejet-pro-8620-wlan-duplexdruck-tintenstrahl-schwarz-multifunktionsgeraet-2583566) (click on the image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy, past and tune this code so it fits your varnames:

```
private void ListBox_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) //Varname
    {

        ImageWindow imageWindow = new ImageWindow { Owner = this };
        foreach (var item in ListBox.Items) //Varname
        {
            imageWindow.ListBox.Items.Add(item);//Varname
        }

        imageWindow.SetSelectedImageIndex = ListBox.SelectedIndex; //Varname + save the index of the selected item and pass it to ImageWindow
        imageWindow.Show();
    }
```

ImageWindow:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Current.MainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
    ListBoxItem lbi = (ListBoxItem)ImageListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(SetSelectedImageIndex); //Get with the index the befor selected item
    lbi.Focus(); //Set the focus on it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start with something like this:

```
<Grid 
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions">

    <Popup x:Name="popup" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=imageList}">
        <Image Source="{Binding PlacementTarget.SelectedItem , ElementName=popup}"/>
    </Popup>
    <ListView x:Name="imageList" >
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="IsOpen" 
                    TargetName="{Binding ElementName=popup}" Value="True"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Add references to **Microsoft.Expression.Interactions** and to **System.Windows.Interactivity** to get it work.